# saas Error building app when using scss file from example code (Sencha Touch 2.3)

Tags: sencha-touch, sass, compass-sass, sencha-touch-theming

This seems to be a saas/scss related issue. I am trying to include some scss code from the example files in Touch 2.3 on Windows 7 to get the 'first time screen'. This is from the sample touchtomatoes app (touch-2.3.0\examples\touchtomatoes\resources\sass).

The scss files in question are as follows:

_welcomeOverlay.scss :

```
.x-ie .welcomeOverlay.x-panel, .x-android-2 .welcomeOverlay.x-panel {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.welcomeOverlay.x-panel {
    @include background-image(radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(0,0,0,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.9)));
    background-color: transparent;

    .x-innerhtml {
        @include st-box;
        @include st-box-orient(vertical);
        @include st-box-align(center);
        @include st-box-pack(center);
        height: 100%;
        color: white;

        .message {
            @include st-box;
            @include st-box-orient(vertical);
            @include st-box-align(center);
            @include st-box-pack(center);
            @include text-shadow(1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.7));

            @include query-medium {
                font-size: 2em;
            }
            @include query-large {
                font-size: 2.2em;
            }

            @include query-small-landscape {
                font-size: .8em;
            }

            h2 {
                text-align: center;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-size: 1.2em;
                padding-bottom:15px;
                color: #41942e;
                em {
                    display: block;
                    color: #125B8F;
                    font-weight: 800;
                    font-size: 1.6em;
                }
            }

            p{
                text-align: center;
                font-weight: 600;
                max-width: 75%;
            }
        }

        .tap {
            padding-top:30px;
            font-weight: 100px;
            font-size: .8em;
        }


    }
}
```

_media-queries.scss:

```
@mixin query-small {
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px){
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin query-small-landscape {
    @media screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-height: 480px){
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin query-medium {
    @media screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width: 1024px){
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin query-large {
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

app.scss:

```
@import "compass/css3";




@import "media-queries";


// The following two lines import the default Sencha Touch theme. If you are building
// a new theme, remove them and the add your own CSS on top of the base CSS (which
// is already included in your app.json file).
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';

@import "welcomeOverlay";


@include icon-font('Pictos', inline-font-files('pictos/pictos-web.woff', woff, 'pictos/pictos-web.ttf', truetype,'pictos/pictos-web.svg', svg));

// Custom code goes here..

// Examples of using the icon mixin:
// @include icon('user');
.tr_select_field_config
{
    font-size:5em !important;
    color:red;
    font-color: blue !important;

}
.result_list_cfg 
{
    font-size:0.8em !important;
    color:red;
}
.no_prod_found_parameters
{
    font-size:0.75em !important;
    color:red;
}
.no_prod_found_label_text
{
    font-size:0.9em !important;
    color:red !important;
}

.home_page_list_text 
{
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
border: 0px solid #0000FF;
background-color:red;

}


.dist_list
{
    font-size:0.9em !important;
    //color:red !important;
}

//@include pictos-iconmask('mail'); 
@include icon('mail'); 


//Import Sencha SAAS
@import "media-queries";

@import "welcomeOverlay";


//New buton color
@include sencha-button-ui('trblue', #0067B0, 'glossy');



//Adding class(es) for list options for users (page 1)

//@include icon('search_black'); 
//@include icon('refresh5'); 
//@include icon('globe1'); 
//@include icon('tabbed_book'); 
//@include icon('phone'); 
//@include icon('mail'); 
//@include icon('globe1');



.userCls:after {
    font-family: "Pictos";
    content: "s";
    //content: "&#x21dd;";
    //icon: "mail";
    font-size: 1.5 em;
}

//End of class(es) for list options
```

Now when I build my app (sencha app build testing) I get the following error:

```
    [INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
Sass::SyntaxError on line ["24"] of C: Invalid CSS after "...de query-medium": expected "}", was "{"
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
    error app.scss (Line 24 of _welcomeOverlay.scss: Invalid CSS after "...de query-medium": expected "}", was "{")
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: compass process exited with non-zero code
 : 1
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 21 seconds
```

Now if I comment the following lines (in _welcomeOverlay.scss), the build goes through well :

```
@include query-medium{
                font-size: 2em;
            }
            @include query-large {
                font-size: 2.2em;
            }

            @include query-small-landscape {
                font-size: .8em;
            }
```

I am new to sass, can anyone help with this please ?

Ravi

Comment: This code appears to compile just fine with Sass/Compass, the error given doesn't even make any sense in the context of the code that it's complaining about.  Do you have a recent version of Sass (3.2+)?

Comment: Thanks, I guess that might the issue. I installed Ruby (1.9.3), compass (0.12.2) and Sass (3.2.12) as advised in this stack overflow post (http://goo.gl/gWFQpG). The compass compile command using this one successfully compiles the app.scss. However on digging up now I find that the Sencha Cmd software (4.0.0.203) comes with it's own compass and sass (3.1.7 - as I can see in C:\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-compass\gems\bin) which is most likely being used and might be causing the problem. How do we get Sencha Touch to use the newer sass?

Comment: On digging up a little more I found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887285/sencha-cmd-sass-version-upgrade

This post referenced - http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?259826

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment: On digging up a little more I found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887285/sencha-cmd-sass-version-upgrade

This post referenced - http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?259826 gives a hack to create links for referencing the ruby directories

Based on the latest comment on Sencha forum thread which mentions that sencha CMD 4.0.0.203 is still bundled with sass-3.1.7 I guess Sencha has still not solved this problem to allow configuring a different versions of ruby-gems for sass. If you know of a clean workaround kindly share. Thanks.

Comment: Cimmanon, thanks a lot for pointing out the problem :-). The workaround as above seems to be the way for now, and it does work.

Comment: I had some issues when I updated sass and compass some time ago. If it helps. I've found when working in sent projects not to rely on my Macs version of ruby or compass. I've used `sencha app watch` from the root of the project to let sencha cmd do the sass compiling. If you're using the build to compile that should be the same thing.